# Microsoft.AspNet.Odata vs Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Odata while adding new web api 2 odata controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api2, odata

The issue is same for both: `VS 2013` and `VS 2015` (c`ommunity edition`).

Although I have installed `Microsoft.AspNet.Odata` via `nuget`, each time I added new controller it installs `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Odata`

Then I should switch back to namespaces given below each time.

Is there way to solve this dependency issue?

Additional information:

`Microsoft.AspNet.Odata` refers to: `OData v4.0`
`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Odata` refers to: `OData v1-3`

Namespaces for Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Odata:

```
using System.Web.Http.OData;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Routing;
```

and

```
using System.Web.OData;
using System.Web.OData.Routing;
```

Comment: Could you please detail, how to add a new controller? Maybe issue coming from there